# window is not defined error in js node.js

Tags: javascript, input, error-handling, window

I have this simple code:

```
do {
    var SioNo = window.prompt("Nicholas ha il cancro, si o no?");
} while (SioNo.toLowerCase() != "si" && SioNo.toLowerCase() != "no");

if (SioNo.toLowerCase() == "si") {
    console.log("Hai il cancro lol");
}
else {
    console.log("ahahahah si come no");
}
```

It's my first time coding in js so i don't really know what to do, i'm using node.js last version and VSCode

**This is the error:**

ReferenceError: window is not defined

at Object. <anonymous (i:.Documenti\Scuola\as_20_21\Informatica\JavaScript\Esercizio1\HelloWorld.js:2:17)

at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)

at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)

at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window` is only found in Browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc).

Executing the above script using `node` without extra packages will not work as the `window` variable simply does not exist in the current context (that is your terminal window).

If you want to do a prompt in NodeJS, which will accept user input from the terminal you can use a native package `readline`.

Here's a solution using recursion instead of a `do...while` loop.

```
const readline = require("readline");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

function askQuestion() {
  rl.question("Nicholas ha il cancro, si o no?", function (result) {
    if (result.toLowerCase() === "si") {
      console.log("Hai il cancro lol");
      process.exit(1);
    } else {
      console.log("ahahahah si come no");
      askQuestion();
    }
  });
}

askQuestion();
```

Since it is your first time using JavaScript / NodeJS, I would recommend going through tutorials and reading the documentation first. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am new in Node js but I have search for the reason. I founded that "window" does not recognized in Node.js, so try this solution by import this library "react" and then use the variable "window" and see if it is recognized:

import React from "react";

read this for more details:
https://morioh.com/p/f7b08fe33a67